# Plaid - Within the Sandbox environment how can i simulate a new transaction taking place and pick this up within the Webhook

Tags: javascript, node.js, webhooks, plaid

I can see how to simulate a DEFAULT_UPDATE event, and pick this up in the webhook, however, i can not see how to simulate a transaction.

I want to simulate a transaction occurring so i can pick this up within the webhook.

Documentation for the sandbox does not show a means to simulating a fake transaction.

Anyone got any ideas

Answer (score 1):

You can use the custom Sandbox configuration object to create a Sandbox account containing a transaction with a future date. When that future date hits, it should trigger an actual DEFAULT_UPDATE webhook to be sent.

For details on configuring custom Sandbox configuration objects you can see https://plaid.com/docs/sandbox/user-custom/#customize-sandbox-account-data

Comment: Hey Alex--just to be clear: there's no way to force an immediate transaction in the sandbox? As a developer, if I want to test that my webhook is working, I have to wait at least a day? This seems like a pretty huge oversight.

Comment: Unfortunately there is not. We have found that for most use cases the endpoint that simulates a DEFAULT_UPDATE webhook seems to work well enough for testing, but we're working on improving Sandbox data and functionality in 2022 and will consider this feedback as part of that!

Comment: It doesn't appear that this problem has been addressed 3 years later. Is there still no way to trigger a transaction?